# Google doc access to anyone but keeping mastercopy as it is

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, google-docs, access-control, google-docs-template

I have one google document - which i like to keep as a master copy/template. I want to allow users without any kind of email/account to access this master copy - edit something and save it to doc file or pdf file. Is it possible?
Any small script or access setting possible ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to open or use Google doc without google account.
Here is what you can do to protect your master template:

1. Create a template and share it publicly view only.
   [image]
2. Grab the url and replace the last path element `/edit` with `/copy`. **Example**:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BKMD8jG5Z6zUds1fonf-Vvt1uA3kAZoS5OCeCZTeFME/copy
3. When a user opens your new link, he will be presented with the dialog below. If he clicks on **Make a copy**, a new copy will be created on his Google drive

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast guidance...I have done the same but it is asking for gmail login. see below link which i have generated... Please suggest something for it...
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ssGtYZSBc8FdI9fa68tr8TOZ7woUpsvkzkniENKnGnM/copy